# Why is my form is POSTING multiple times and Socket emitting multiple events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, twitter-streaming-api

- I have a form that starts a stream via `router.post()` when `start
  button` is clicked. When start button is clicked.
- When stop button is clicked, i emit a socket `event` which stops the
  streaming from server.
- I use on_stream boolean to set true/false flags for starting/stopping stream.

> **PROBLEM:** When the start/stop button is clicked for FIRST time, the stream starts and stops correctly. **The second time, when start button
>   is clicked the router.post() is posting TWICE to server. And when STOP
>   button is clicked the socket event emits twice.**

**From this point, start/stop buttons trigger exponentially multiple post requests (Starting) and socket events (stopping stream). Crashing the code...**

**Console after starting and stopping second time (multiple post and socket events)**

```
Stoping Stream...
SOCKET DEF: true
Closing stream...
close stream:  false
startz undefined
POST DEF: false
startStream DEF: true
starting stream...
POST / 200 12.608 ms - 4
startz undefined
POST DEF: true
startStream DEF: true
starting stream...
```

Browser Console *(events triggered multiple times)*:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACEvJ.jpg

index.js

```
module.exports = function(io) {
  let _stream = {};
  let on_stream = false;

 router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // console.log("raw obj " + req.body.searchTerm);
    console.log("startz " + req.body.startBtn);
    console.log("POST DEF:", on_stream);

    startStream(req.body.searchTerm);

    res.send(on_stream);
});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('a user connected index outside routerrr');

  // Listen to stop Button being clicked
  socket.on('stopStream', function()  {
    console.log("Stoping Stream...");
    if(on_stream) {
      console.log("SOCKET DEF:", on_stream);
      closeStream();
    }
  });

});

// start stream
function startStream(term) {
  // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // console.log("TERM _" +term);
    client.stream('statuses/filter', { track: term }, function(stream) {
      _stream = stream;
      on_stream = true;
      console.log("startStream DEF:", on_stream);

      console.log("starting stream...");
      _stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
      console.log(tweet.text + "Streaming");
          // socket.emit('tweet', tweet.text);
      });

      _stream.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("erorr:: " + error);
          throw error;
      });
    });
}  


function closeStream() {
  console.log('Closing stream...');
  _stream.destroy();
  on_stream = false;
  console.log("close stream: ", on_stream );
}

   return router;
}
```

script.js

```
function startSearchForm() {
   $("#startBtn").on('click', function() {

        let form = $("#search-form");
        let query = form.serialize();
        console.log(query);
        $.post('/', query);
   });  
}
function stopSearchForm() {
    $("#stopBtn").on('click', function() {
        let startSearchValue = $("#searchTerm").val("");
        console.log("Stop Stream...");
        socket.emit('stopStream', function(data) {
            console.log("Stream Stop Complete");
        });

        // let form = $("#searchStop-form");
        // let query = form.serialize();
        // console.log(query);
        // $.post('/', query);
   }); 
}
```

index.pug

```
  form#search-form(action='javascript:startSearchForm()', method='POST')
    input(type="text" id="searchedTerm" name="searchTerm" placeholder="#hastag" required)
    button(type="submit"  name="startBtn" id="startBtn") Search

  form#searchStop-form(action='javascript:stopSearchForm()', method='POST')
    input(type="text" id="stopSearch" name="stopSearch" value="stopSearch" hidden)
    button(type="submit" id="stopBtn" name="stopBtn") Stop
```

Comment: You’ve made sure the `startSearchForm` isn’t being called multiple times?

Comment: Well, if you look at the image link of browser console, the click number (for start/stop) seem to be increasing... which I'm not sure why but startSearchForm is only called when the first form is submitted (check the index.pug file)

Comment: I am not calling the startSearchForm() anywhere else in script..

Comment: I don’t know pug, but do make sure it’s not called multiple times. And if it’s called when the form is submitted then couldn’t it be called each time it’s submitted, that is, more than once?

Comment: That is an interesting point. But as far as I know, when the submit button is clicked I trigger the startSearchForm which posts via $.post(), I don't see how it would submit multiple times...

Comment: But startSearchForm doesn’t do post. It adds a handler that does it. Add a breakpoint, logging, whatever and make sure. Don’t assume.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `console.log('router.post() called');` above `router.post('/', async (req, res) => {`. This problem has the feel of registering an event handler multiple times.

Comment: You're right guys! Each time I click start, the POST is triggering 1+n times. How do I unregister previous events startSearchForm. I didn't think that was a thing - new to javascript!

Comment: How about just removing lines `$("#startBtn").on('click', function() {` and `$("#stopBtn").on('click', function() {` (and the closing `});` for each)? Looks like `startSearchForm` and `stopSearchForm` are being called on click already so let them do the work. Note: I'm not familiar with .pug so my suggestions include some guess work.

Comment: @RockySims Yup! Its works, it was that simple! It was firing the event twice. if you want to post it as answer i'll give you the check

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just removing lines `$("#startBtn").on('click', function() {` and `$("#stopBtn").on('click', function() {` (and the closing `});` for each)? Looks like `startSearchForm` and `stopSearchForm` are being called on click already so let them do the work.